# ng-bind how to create expression

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

I have a branch of code here:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in allTickets | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse|filter:searchTicket track by $index">
                <td>{{ticket.id}}</td>
                <td><a th:href="@{overview/{{ticket.id}}}">{{ticket.name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{ticket.desiredResolutionDate}}</td>
                <td>{{ticket.urgency}}</td>
                <td>{{ticket.state}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind="action+$index"></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="changeAction('approve',$index)">Approve</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="changeAction('decline',$index)">Decline</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="changeAction('submit',$index)">Submit</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="changeAction('cancel',$index)">Cancel</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="changeAction('assign',$index)">Assign to me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="changeAction('done',$index)">Done</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="changeAction('leavefeedback',$index)">Leave Feedback</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" ng-click="changeAction('viewfeedback',$index)">View Feedback</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Controller function:

```
$scope.changeAction = function (action, index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            $scope.action0 = action;
        }
        else if (index == 1) {
            $scope.action1 = action;
        } else if (index == 2) {
            $scope.action2 = action;
        } else if (index == 3) {
            $scope.action3 = action;
        } else if (index == 4) {
            $scope.action4 = action;
        } else if (index == 5) {
            $scope.action5 = action;
        } else if (index == 6) {
            $scope.action6 = action;
        } else if (index == 7) {
            $scope.action7 = action;
        }
    }
```

And I want to change my button value when clicking on dropdown item. I want to bind all button values to expression like 'action'+$index, so as a result I want to get binded the first button to 'action0', the second to 'action1' etc. My example doesn't work.

Comment: Questions regarding angular 1.x versions shoukld be tagged as `angular.js`, not `angular`

Comment: Did you simply forget to quote the 'action' ? in your description it is quoted but not in the code `ng-bind="action+$index" `   -> try  `ng-bind="'action'+$index"`

Answer (score 0):

To use a "dynamic" `ng-bind` value you can use this to make action0, action1, etc.

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind="{{ 'action' + $index }}"></button>
```